# Not able to Create Web services in RAD 7.5 using WAS 6.1

Tags: web-services, websphere, ibm-rad-7.5

I just installed Rational application developer (`RAD`) 7.5. I am trying to create a web service in `RAD 7.5` using `WAS 6.1` but when trying to create the service it's giving me a message that:

`"The project is targeted against a server without IBM WebSphere JAX-WS support.  Continuing code generation will result in compilation errors.".`

I tried installing feature packs for Web services but not able to do so.
I was able to easily create the Web service in RAD 7.0 with same WAS 6.1.

Please help in how to procees from here.

Comment: How did you manage to create a JAX-WS service without having Feature Pack for Web Services installed in WAS 6.1?

Comment: I was able to create in RAD 7.0 but when I upgraded to RAD 7.5 I started getting this message. I googled and try uadding this feature for Web Service but not able to do so.